# Finding minimum of the input numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
small = None
larg = None
count = 0

while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : break

    try:
        num = float (inp)

    except:
        print "Invalid number"

    if num < small:
        small = num

print "Done"
print small
```

This code should make user add numbers until he/she types "done" and then find the smallest number (my idea is to compare num with small each time and it print last small value after done)

But when I run it, it keep showing `None` as the smallest value.

Comment: Maybe it's better to let user type all numbers and then show smallest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.x , `None` is smaller than all numbers, hence since your starting number is `None` , its always the smallest.

You can put a check that if small is `None` to initialize with the input ( this should set your `small` to the first inputted number).

Example -

```
small = None
larg = None
count = 0

while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : break

    try:
        num = float (inp)

    except:
        print "Invalid number"

    if small is None or num < small:
        small = num

print "Done"
print small
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initiate `small` as `None` value initially. Otherwise your statemtent

```
if num < small:
```

will evaluate to `False` everytime. Because you are comparing `None` value with a float value and `None` is smaller than every number.  Do something like this

```
if small is None or num < small:
    small = num
```

Comment: What if the user enters all numbers greater than 9999999?

Comment: yea thanks that give some advantage of making code smaller :D

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest something like this

```
input_list = []

while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : break

    try:
        input_list.append(float(inp))
    except:
        print "Invalid number"
        continue

    smalest = min(input_list[-2:])
    print smalest

    input_list.append(input_list.pop(input_list.index(smalest)))

print "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple way of doing it. I haven't tried breaking it by typing gibberish into the prompt but I think it works ok.

```
numbers = []

def asking():
    while True:
        number = raw_input("Enter a number:")
        if number == "stop":
            break
        try:
            number = float(number)
            numbers.append(number)
        except:
            print "Try again."
            continue

    return min(numbers)

print asking()
```